# A generic internal error page should be shown when an unexpected exception is thrown in wicket6.x or wicket7.7?

Tags: wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-7

```
protected void init() {
        getApplicationSettings().setInternalErrorPage(BnafInternalErrorPage.class);
        getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(BnafAccessDeniedErrorPage.class);
        getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(BnafAccessDeniedErrorPage.class);
        getExceptionSettings().setInternalErrorPage(IExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);
```

In above code i got error at IExceptionSettings.

Comment: Can you update your question with full details please?

Comment: i have code like

Comment: getExceptionSettings().setInternalErrorPage(IExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);

Comment: i am getting error at IExceptionSettin‌​gs in wicket 1.4.9

Comment: wicket 1.4 or wicket 7 ?

Comment: insted can any one suggest ,how to do in wicket6.x

Comment: error  in wicket 7

Comment: what error what did you change ?

Answer (score 1):

`IExceptionSettings` removed in wicket 7

So you can replace this  below line.

```
getExceptionSettings().setInternalErrorPage(IExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);
```

to

```
getExceptionSettings().setUnexpectedExceptionDisplay(ExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);
```

To know more details check  here
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+7.0#MigrationtoWicket7.0-AllIXyzSettingsareremovedWICKET-5410

Comment: well glad to hear that.

Comment: Use simple code in constructors (Panel/Pages etc) and no code which can fails. Wicket exceptions catchers works in rendering phase.